# How to print a date using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE?

Tags: java, date, java-8, date-formatting, java-time

I want to use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` to print and parse dates. This is what I'm doing for printing:

```
Date date;
String text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(
  date.toInstant()
);
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year
  at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
  at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext$1.getLong(DateTimePrintContext.java:205)
  at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2543)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1744)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1718)
```

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: Works fine here Java 1.8

Comment: my bad, updated the question, it was printing, not parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
String text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
  .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
  .format(date.toInstant());
```

Comment: Instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, you can also use the built-in constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-), they're equivalent: *"If the zone ID equals 'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT' then the result is a ZoneId with the same ID and rules equivalent to ZoneOffset.UTC"*

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `Instant` class represents a point in the timeline: the number of nanoseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`), without any concept of timezone - so it doesn't have a specific date/time (day/month/year, hours/minutes/seconds), as it can represent a different date and time in different timezones.

Setting a specific zone in the formatter, [like you did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805978/7605325), converts the `Instant` to that zone (so the count of nanoseconds since epoch can be translated to a specific date and time), making it possible to be formatted.

For this specific case, you want only the date part (day, month and year) in [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates), so one alternative is to convert the `Instant` to a `LocalDate` and call the `toString()` method. As you set UTC in the formatter, I'm using the same to convert it:

```
String text = date.toInstant()
    // convert to UTC
    .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // get the date part
    .toLocalDate()
    // toString() returns the date in ISO8601 format
    .toString();
```

This return the same thing as [your formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805978/7605325). Of course for another formats, you should use the formatter, but specifically for ISO8601, you can use the `toString()` method.

---

You could also convert the `Instant` to the timezone you want (in this case, to UTC) and pass it directly to the formatter:

```
String text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(
    date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
);
```

The only difference is that, when you set the zone in the formatter, the date is converted to that zone when formatting (when you don't set it, the date is not converted).